# right-click "mouse gestures" on touchpad

Tags: firefox, mouse, browser-addons, touchpad, firefox-extensions

Most touchpads support drag-and-drop (dragging with the mouse left button) using a double-tap action.

Many useful software add-ons (like Firefox FireGestures) define complex gestures based on dragging the mouse right button.

Is there any way to support such mouse gestures on a touchpad, perhaps using a two-finger double-tap action?

Even better would be to use a 3-finger or 4-finger "swipe" action to directly enter the mouse gesture, without having to tap.

(I am running Windows with an ElanTech touchpad, and can't find any registry setting which would enable these modes of interaction.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with ElanTech touch pad on my Asus Zenbook. My touch pad buttons are located below the actual touchpad. If you're touchpad buttons are configured this way, then you should be able to activate the left hardware button by applying pressure anywhere on the left half of the touchpad. Activating the right hardware button, however, requires pressing a much smaller area in the bottom-right corner as shown below.

[image]

If you swap the functions of the touchpad buttons, you will be able to keep the left hardware button depressed while sliding your finger to complete Fire Gesture commands. You can swap the left and right hardware button functions by going into the Elan Smart-Pad application ->  "One-Finger" tab -> "Button" on the side menu as below:

[image]

This will not affect the tapping functionality and you can still use one- and two-finger taps to execute right and left clicks.